# MS SQL order by date, time(AM/PM)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to order by date and time but the time is in am/pm format so I tried to convert it to military time but it still doesn't work correctly. **CRT_DATE is data type: date and CRTUP_TIME is nvarchar**

```
MyQuery = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ACTIVE=1 and ORIGINAL_P=2 ORDER BY CRT_DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CRTUP_TIME, 108)"
```

Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong ? Thanks so much for any help!! :)

Comment: @shawnt00 hi,  no its a date

Comment: Why are you storing the time as nvarchar???? There are exactly 0 characters in a time value that required the extended character set. Why store it as character data at all? why not store it as TIME???

Comment: Never, ever store timestamps a `varchar`. Never.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CONVERT()` doing essentially nothing in terms of type conversion.  Your converting an `nvarchar` to a `varchar`.  You need to convert it to a `TIME` data type, to sort accordingly.  Try instead:

```
CONVERT(TIME,CRTUP_TIME)
```

Comment: Why this is accepted as answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need to convert CRTUP_TIME.  However, if CRTUP_TIME contains actual time like "10:05:44:00 AM", your conversion limited to only the first 8 characters resulting "10:05:44" and truncating the rest.

Comment: is this the full answer?